# Can two process share same classsame?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

From my C# application I call [`FindWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) like this:

```
FindWindow("#32770", "title goes here")
```

My question is: Can two process share the same classname? (If matter, I'm clicking in "ok" button on a dialog box raised by the WebBrowser in my application) I'm afraid of requesting to find process with `#32770` classname and this return the process I'm  not looking for. If I can share same classname, how can I make sure that classname is from a specific process? Maybe filter by process's path to make sure it's unique? I hope it's clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There is no restriction on window class names to be unique across processes. Each process registers its own classes, and every process is free to call they main window class "MainWindowClass".

In your case you are looking for system-wide "dialog" class, which definitely can be used by multiple processes.

> `#32770`  The class for a dialog box.

Detailed info can be found in [About Window Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks, how can I make sure that classname is from a specific process? Maybe filter by process's path to make sure it's unique?

Comment: @Jack path not going to help since same executable may be running multiple times. Process handle (native) is the unique identifier of process. If you are interested in particular process - consider to get its top level window and start searching with [FindWindowEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500.aspx)

Comment: I tried it `FindWindowEx(webBrowser1.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, "#32770", "title goes here");` but it only returns `IntPtr.Zero`

Comment: Isn't the `webBrowser1.Handle` the WebBrowser's top level window where the button is in (since it was raised by it)? using `this.Handle` didn't worked either.